# números aleatorios con sensor en python

Tags: python

Quiero publicar números aleatorios de temperatura y humedad desde una raspberry ya tengo el código pero no quiero publicar los datos que me arroje el sensor quiero que sean números random pero no se donde hacerlo y si es necesario incluir la librería del dth ya que ese mismo código lo quiero reutilizar

```
import os
import time
import sys
#import Adafruit_DHT as dht
#import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

THINGSBOARD_HOST = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''

# Data capture and upload interval in seconds. Less interval will eventually hang the DHT22.
INTERVAL=2

sensor_data = {'temperature': 0, 'humidity': 0}

next_reading = time.time() 

client = mqtt.Client()

# Set access token
client.username_pw_set(ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Connect to ThingsBoard using default MQTT port and 60 seconds keepalive interval
client.connect(THINGSBOARD_HOST, 8080, 60)

client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        humidity,temperature = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
        humidity = round(humidity, 2)
        temperature = round(temperature, 2)
        print(u"Temperature: {:g}\u00b0C, Humidity: {:g}%".format(temperature, humidity))
        sensor_data['temperature'] = temperature
        sensor_data['humidity'] = humidity

        # Sending humidity and temperature data to ThingsBoard
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)

        next_reading += INTERVAL
        sleep_time = next_reading-time.time()
        if sleep_time > 0:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 4):

La línea que dice

```
humidity,temperature = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
```

reemplazala por

```
humidity = random.uniform(0, 100)
temperature = random.uniform(-10, 40)
```

pensando que la humedad relativa oscila entre 0 y 100%, mientras que la temperatura ambiente lo hace entre -10°C y 40°C (a menos que estés en Siberia o en el Sahara).

Esta alternativa no produce un buen gráfico, ya que temperatura y humedad saltaran de un valor a otro, lo que no corresponde a la realidad física.

Una mejor alternativa es partir de un valor dado e ir dando pequeños incrementos/decrementos para simular la evolución real de temp/humedad. Además, existe una relación inversa entre temperatura y humedad (a mayor temperatura, menor humedad).

En este código aplicamos esa lógica, además de corregir los valores cuando se salen de rango:

```
import random

temp = random.uniform(-10, 40)
humedad = random.uniform(0, 100)

for i in range(10):
    temp = round(temp, 2)
    humedad = round(humedad, 2)
    print(temp, humedad)

    variacion = random.uniform(0, 1)
    temp -= variacion
    humedad -= 2 * variacion
    if temp < -10:
        temp = -10
    elif temp > 40:
        temp = 40
    if humedad < 0:
        humedad = 0
    elif humedad > 100:
        humedad = 100
```

produce:

```
3.46 56.82
3.39 56.68
2.97 55.85
2.07 54.05
1.57 53.05
1.39 52.68
0.79 51.48
0.27 50.44
-0.71 48.49
-1.46 46.99
```

**random.uniform(a, b)**

> Retorna un número en coma flotante aleatorio N tal que a <= N <= b
> para a <= b y b <= N <= a para b < a.
>
> El valor final b puede o no estar incluido en el rango, dependiendo
> del redondeo de coma flotante en la ecuación a + (b-a) * random().